# What does $P$ in blackboard bold type of letter stand for? $\Bbb P$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

In the first post of the thread "Cardinal number subtraction",

[Cardinal number subtraction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140930/cardinal-number-subtraction)

there is a symbol for some kind of set which looks like this:  $\Bbb P$

I am familiar with symbols for natural ($\mathbb{N}$), rational ($\mathbb{Q}$), real ($\mathbb{R}$), complex ($\mathbb{C}$) numbers, which are all written in blackboard bold type. I am not a mathematician, but I have encountered all kinds of mathematical symbols, but not this one. I am very curious about this symbol. Does it stand for something?

Alex

Comment: Thanks for the edit; now it looks better with blackboard bold type of letters. :-)

Answer (score 5):

I have seen $\mathbb{P}$ used for primes and for irrationals. I believe, from the context of the question you mention, that it was primes. I would not recommend using it without defining it as the notation is not as standard as the notation you mention.

Comment: I agree - in the context of the linked question it should be primes

Comment: A sort of tangential remark, if my interpretation is correct they should have written $\mathbb{N} \setminus \mathbb{P}$ instead of $\mathbb{P} \setminus \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Yep, that part confused me for a bit too

Answer (score 1):

It could mean anything. From a partial order to the set of primes, to a probability function.

In the context of that question, I'm guessing it meant the set of primes, and the observation that $|\Bbb{P\setminus N}|=\aleph_0$ was supposed to be $|\Bbb{N\setminus P}|$ instead.

But it doesn't matter for the context of the question $\Bbb P$ can be any countable infinite set which contains infinitely many elements which are not in $\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of sets, if $X$ is a set the notation $\mathbb{P}(X)$ can be used to mean the [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of $X$. However, this is not universal notation, and the power set can also be referred to as $\mathcal{P}(X)$ or simply $P(X)$.

Comment: In the post, it was written like this:

Well, |ℙ|=ℵ0, and |ℙ∖ℕ|=ℵ0, so perhaps ℵ0−ℵ0=ℵ0?

I am not sure if it can denote powerset, but perhaps the set of prime numbers, as it was mentioned by Disciple of Barney?

Comment: @AleksandarKatanovic Yeah, I looked at the post, and I agree with DiscipleofBarney's answer.

Comment: Script P stands for power sets but $\mathbb{P}(n)$ normally stands for the space of polynomials of order n

Comment: @AleksandarKatanovic (Though my answer is still valid for general use of the notation $\mathbb{P}$)

Comment: @Dan I think your statement would be reasonable as a separate answer if you wanted to post it.

Comment: Thanks Peter Woolfitt, usually this is how I interpret linear algebra

Answer (score 0):

$\mathcal{P}(A)$ usually stands for the power set of a set A, meanwhile the set $\mathbb{P}(n)$ normally stands for the space of polynomials of order n