# Are these sets in the correct order according to cardinality?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cardinals

$$
\{3,7\} = P(\{1\}) < P(\{2,5\}) < P(\{\Bbb Q\}) = \Bbb R \setminus \{\pi, e\} = \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Z = \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb N < P(\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q)
$$
Where P is power set, R is the Reals, and N is the natural numbers

Comment: Hi @Julia199827, usually on Math.SE it's important to ask a question proactively, including what you've tried already, your thoughts on the problem, and the specific point(s) where you're feeling stuck. People often look poorly on questions like this, and are less likely to give helpful answers. You should consider editing your question with this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but there is a simple mistake. $P(\{\mathbb{Q}\}) = \left\{\emptyset, \left\{\mathbb{Q}\right\}\right\}$, and $P(\mathbb{Q})$ is the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$.

$\{3,7\}$ and $P(\{1\}) = \left\{\emptyset, \left\{1\right\}\right\}$ has 2 elements. $P(\{2,5\}) = \left\{\emptyset, \left\{2\right\}, \left\{5\right\}, \left\{2, 5\right\}\right\}$ has 4 elements.

For $P(\mathbb{Q})$, you can look [Cardinality of the Continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_the_continuum), and [Cardinal Number Subtraction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140930/cardinal-number-subtraction) for the rest.

Since $\{\pi, e\}<\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is infinite and $\mathbb{Z}<\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{N}<\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}<\mathbb{R}$ according to the cardinality, $$\mathbb{R} \cong P(\Bbb Q) \cong \Bbb R \setminus \{\pi, e\} \cong \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Z \cong \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb N \cong \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$$

and finally, $P(\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q) \cong P(\mathbb{R}) > \mathbb{R}$ by the Cantor's Theorem.